# Javafx: write code only for a part of a fxml interface

Tags: javafx

I know my title is a little too generic, but I sincerely have no idea how to ask it. So, the topic is JavaFX. I have a part of the interface coming from a fxml file and another part that I'd like to code manually. So my question is, more specifically, is there a way to insert a sort of pane into another, coming from scene builder? If you have "questions about my question", please, ask me!

Comment: Might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122084/how-to-add-children-component-and-new-attribute-to-custom-javafx-control

Comment: I've no idea where we'd need to start with the explanation. Controller classes? Modifying a scene from java code? Injection of fields?

Comment: I think "modify a scene from java code", but the problem is that I've no idea where insert the code

Comment: I recommend you take a couple of JavaFX tutorials. The [official Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm) are a decent introduction.

Comment: http://gjf2a.blogspot.com/2015/01/dynamically-adding-javafx-controls.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to dynamically add a label on button click, thanks to your suggestions.
Anyway, i tried to add imageviews, but i get a lot of error! This is my code:

```
        ImageView pages[] = new ImageView[8];
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        pages[i] = new ImageView(new Image(FlowLayout.class.getResourceAsStream("src/provaProgetto/Penguins.jpg")));
        base.getChildren().add(pages[i]);
    }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Ask a new question don't post another question as an answer. Post how you solved your problem accept the answer then post a new question with your new question